# Error in Mongoose. ValidatorError: Path `product` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Could you please help me. I am following this tutorial:
"Managing Orders with Mongoose | Creating a REST API with Node.js"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKuY8QscZwY&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q&index=8
It is quite old (2017) but still good I think. But I got stuck (about 8 min.).
Doing a POST request the same way as in the tutorial leads me to an Error. I have read previous topics like this, comments under the video, but I did not find the answer. Here is the code:

**Order Scheme**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  },
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

**Product Scheme**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

**Post Order Route**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Order = require('../models/order');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const order = new Order({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId,
  });
  order
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

**Request**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/orders
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "quantity": "10",
    "poductId": "5fae9023c8e7ac3e54ae6752"    
}
```

**I am getting:**

```
Error: Order validation failed: product: Path `product` is required.

{
  "error": {
    "errors": {
      "product": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `product` is required.",
        "properties": {
          "message": "Path `product` is required.",
          "type": "required",
          "path": "product"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "product"
      }
    },
    "_message": "Order validation failed",
    "message": "Order validation failed: product: Path `product` is required."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a typo in your request JSON

```js
{
    "quantity": "10",
    "poductId": "5fae9023c8e7ac3e54ae6752" ---> change this to productId (missing `r`)   
}
```

Comment: No way! Seriously? I have been going through the code for 2 days in a row, but the typo was in the request. Thank you so much!